# Why is the sitemap validator returning an error for the "lastmod" tag?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, xml, date-format

The sitemap of my company's brand's website seems to be fine when I look at it at first glance. I don't particularly see any errors as such. However, SEMrush, the SEO tool, reports that our sitemap is not in the correct format. SEMrush doesn't tell me what's wrong. It just says that the format is incorrect.

So, I submitted the sitemap to this online validator:

https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/index.php?op=validate-xml-sitemap&go=1&sitemapurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.photojaanic.com%2Fsitemap.xml&submit=Validate+Sitemap

It says no issues found. But, when I run it through another tool:

http://tools.seochat.com/tools/site-validator/

It returns several errors for the `lastmod` tags. Here's one of them:

> ```xml
> <url><loc>http://www.photojaanic.com/photo-gifts/keychains</loc>
> <lastmod>2017-07-24T04:37Z</lastmod><changefreq>yearly</changefreq></url>
> ```
>
> Error 1826: Element `'{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}lastmod'`:
> `'2017-07-24T04:37Z'` is not a valid value of the union type
> `'{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}tLastmod'`. on line: 5 column: 0

**Could this be the reason why the sitemap is wrong? I wonder why the date-time format is wrong.**

I also tried another validator. Even that one returns many errors along with the `lastmod` issue:

http://freetools.webmasterworld.com/tools/site-validator

I'm not so concerned about the other errors as they're related to video or images. That could be rectified. What I'm concerned is about the `lastmod` tag.

A way to get around the `lastmod` issue could be to simply exclude the time. However, I'd like to know why there's an error.

Comment: Google doesn't even use the `lastmod` field in sitemaps.   Just take it out along with `priority` and `changefreq`.   Just leave in the `url` and any `hreflang`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the schema, `tLastMod` is the union of `xsd:date` and `xsd:dateTime`.

Since you provide hours, you are not in the first case, so your string should conform to the XSD `dateTime` type, and it does not: you need to specify the part with seconds.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/#dateTime-lexical-mapping for the full format.

So, if you try with `2017-07-24T04:37:00Z` the validation error on this element should go away.

Comment: Interesting (+1). So the spec (which I based [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/112226/17633) on) and the schema (which you based your answer on) seem to be in conflict, right? The spec says W3C Datetime format, but the schema is more restrictive.

Comment: The link you quote is note the norm, just a note. The norm I have referenced clearly say the seconds are mandatory. Note that your note is from 2007, the norm from 2012.

Comment: Yes, but this W3C Note is referenced by the sitemaps specification page as well as by the schema, which says (in `xsd:documentation`): "The date must conform to the W3C DATETIME format (`http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime`)." So the sitemaps specification references exactly this W3C Note, but specifies the schema in a different way. -- My interpretation is that the spec (not the schema) is normative for authors (it’s what they read/follow after all; most probably don’t read the schema itself).

Comment: The `xsd:documentation` is not the normative part, and it can be ignored. The sitemap schema uses `xsd:date` and `xsd:dateTime` and you have `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` on top so this is the only norm to follow. If you go there you can follow to `https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/` aka "*W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 2: Datatypes*" and its `dateTime` part has the full definition. This is the norm, do not rely on what you find in documentation. The `sitemap` doc was written before so its documentation referenced something else, now obsolete.

Comment: The subject comes regularly, like in IETF circles or such. The normative part of a definition is always the schema (or equivalent, since there are multiple ways to write it), not the accompanying text/documentation. Because the later could be ambiguous to parse, where the former should not be. The text is here to help understand the schema, but the schema is the king.

Comment: In fact from the same norm you can read about `xsd:documentation` or its parent `xsd:annotation`. Quote: "*Annotations do not participate in ·validation· as such. Provided an annotation itself satisfies all relevant ·Schema Component Constraints· it cannot affect the ·validation· of element information items.*".  You can remove `xsd:annotation` elements from any XML schema file, and things will work the exact same way validation-wise.

Comment: I’m well aware of that. I didn’t mean that the parts in `xsd:documentation` are normative (it’s part of the schema file after all, which I claim not to be normative), but the spec (i.e., https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html), because a) it’s what authors read (as not all of them can be expected to understand the XML), and b) this spec also defines the other sitemap formats (for which there is no XML schema or equivalent to begin with). -- I can see that it can make sense for standards to make the technical specification normative, but not for standards that target non-technical web authors.

Comment: But all this is moot anyway, as it really depends on each individual project’s decision, and the sitemaps sponsors didn’t seem to make one explicitly, so it’s just speculation here. -- They should fix the conflict (either by editing the spec to allow only the XSD formats, or by creating a new schema).

Comment: We will remain in disagreement while I can understand your point. https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html is only human documentation, this would never be considered a norm. Human documentation can have errors (as we both just discovered) and it should be fixed if possible, yes. Authors of tool generating sitemaps should read it indeed, not webmasters, as maintaining a sitemap by hand is surely not a great idea. Authors of tool generating sitemap should be versed in XML stuff as this is technical, and hence relying more on the XML schema as it is here than on the human documentation.

Comment: Note the first line: "This document **describes** the XML schema for the Sitemap protocol." (emphasis mine).

Comment: Thank you so much @PatrickMevzek. It seems a bit complicated - the documentation v/s actual schema part. I'll give the above solution a try.

Answer (score 2):

The tool http://tools.seochat.com/tools/site-validator/ gives no error when also specifying the seconds:

```xml
<lastmod>2017-07-24T04:37:00Z</lastmod>
```

Are the seconds required for a datetime? There is a conflict in the spec vs. the schema:

- According to the spec for [`lastmod`](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#lastmoddef), specifying the seconds isn’t required for datetimes. The `lastmod` element uses the "[W3C Datetime format](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)", according to which your datetime is valid.
- According to the XML schema, specifying the seconds is required for datetimes ([as Patrick Mevzek’s answer points out](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/112225/17633)).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure none of your  values are blank. I troubleshooted this for a while and realized my "last edit date" field for certain entries was blank and thus it was causing markup errors in the XML file due to nothing populating for certain URLs